# Как создать массив от 1 до определённого числа с помощью Array()?

Tags: javascript

Как создать массив от 1 до 10 с помощью Array()?

Что я имею ввиду:

```
???Array()???  ---> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов, зачем на английском?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, я тут не виновен, это из этой серии https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9832/256824

Comment: @РустамГимранов, однако хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, вы бы лучше у отвечающих поинтересовались зачем они на дубликат ответы шпарят.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, репу набивают, очевидно же ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @РустамГимранов, затем что оба вопроса низкого качества, и выбирать между ними сложно. Если тебя так возмущает что "шпарят ответы к дубликату", запили эталонный самоответ (с нас плюсы)... чего впустую шуметь-то в комментах?

Comment: вопрос такой. что ответ быстрее написать, чем дубль  найти

Comment: @teran, да ладно, че там искать [site:ru.stackoverflow.com javascript создать массив чисел с помощью Array](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com%20javascript%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20Array&lr=75)

Comment: @РустамГимранов у вас поисковый запрос длиннее ответов ниже. я об этом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Более универсальное решение

```js
console.log(Array(10).fill().map((e, i) => i + 1));
```

Comment: вариация `[...Array(10)].map((e, i) => i + 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Конструктор `Array()` не так удобен, по сравнению со статическим методом [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (ES6+):

```js
const arr = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (v, i) =>  i + 1); 
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: минус мой если что. ибо в заголовке вопроса подразумевается, что аргумент не статичное 10 ("_до определенного числа_")